# This limit needs to be computed

Tags: limits

I need to compute the following limit:$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt{x^2+2x}}{x}$$
It's quite hard because i'm not able to use L'Hospital's Rule, yet I'm trying to use the derivatite of the function $$g(x)=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt{x^2+2x}$$
Can someone figure it out please ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I like the phrasing of your title, as if the little limit were screaming out, "I ***need*** to be computed!" :)

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Convince yourself that the second square root is negligible compared to the first.  Then pull a factor $x$ out of the first square root and cancel that with the denominator.  What are you left with?

Comment: Thank you. The limit is equal to infinity !!

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use any rule or approximation.

Just substitute $0^+$ in $x$ and compute it to $+\infty$.